# How to access Infrared Camera of Smartphone using Dart and Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Xaiomi POCO F1 which has integrated infrared face camera sensors. I was wondering how to access them using Dart and flutter framework. There are no APIs available for the same on pub.dev.

Comment: If there is nothing on pub.dev yet then it sounds like an opportunity for you to make one or, if you can't, you may want to post to the Google group or Reddit that one is needed and maybe someone who can will take up the challenge. ... 
 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/flutter-dev ...  ... 
 https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/

Comment: In that case you have to use platform channels to implement that natively in that platform. Check this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Thank yoy for your responses. I would like to work on it natively and hopefully add a package in pub.dev